# How to split a url

Tags: r

I want to split the below string in R

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=797998

Here I want to split the URL and only want to get the value as 797998.

Comment: If you need the numbers, `library(stringr); str_extract(url1, perl('(?<=id=)[0-9]+'))
[1] "797998"`

Answer (score 2):

```
> library('httr')
> parse_url('https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=797998')
$scheme
[1] "https"

$hostname
[1] "bugzilla.mozilla.org"

$port
NULL

$path
[1] "show_bug.cgi"

$query
$query$id
[1] "797998"


$params
NULL

$fragment
NULL

$username
NULL

$password
NULL

attr(,"class")
[1] "url"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the url suggestion above, however if it's stored as a string then a couple of options are:

```
str <- "https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=797998"

# If you know it will follow the only '=' in the string
(num <- unlist(strsplit(str, "="))[2])

# If you know that the number is always the last 6 digits
(num <- substr(str, nchar(str)-5, nchar(str)))

# If you know the number always follows the last '=' sign
revstr <- rev(unlist(strsplit(str, NULL)))
index <- which(revstr == "=")
revnum <- revstr[1:(index-1)]
(num <- paste(rev(revnum), collapse = ""))
```

Note, you'd have to convert these to numeric, using `as.numeric()`, if you wanted a number.  Otherwise, they are currently given as character strings.