# Split domain and path using R regex

Tags: r

I have a dataset with URLs that I want to split using a regex. I have created a regex that I belive works, however I am unsure how to implement it in R.

This is my regex:

```
- Domain: ^(.*[\\\/])
- Path:   (\/[0-9].*\?|$)
```

```
# Libraries
library(tidyr) # function separate, extract


# 1. Read data
df = read.csv2(text = "datetime|url
2021-05-29 16:57:09|https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67755241/how-do-i-put-row-data-from-a-database-into-a-php-variable
2021-05-29 16:58:09|https://stackoverflow.com/
2021-05-29 16:59:09|https://stackoverflow.com/hacker
2021-05-29 17:00:09|https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?so_medium=StackOverflow&so_source=SiteNav
2021-05-29 17:01:09|http://www.bbc.co.uk/
2021-05-29 17:02:09|http://www.bbc.com/weather/2643743?day=3",
               sep="|",stringsAsFactors=F, na.strings="unknown");


# 2. Split URL into domain and path
# Domain: ^(.*[\\\/])
# Path:   (\/[0-9].*\?|$)
df <- df %>% extract(url, c("Domain", "Path"), "^(.*[\\\\/])(\\/[0-9].*\\?|$)") # 


df
```

This produces the following:

```
##              datetime                     Domain Path
## 1 2021-05-29 16:57:09                       <NA> <NA>
## 2 2021-05-29 16:58:09 https://stackoverflow.com/     
## 3 2021-05-29 16:59:09                       <NA> <NA>
## 4 2021-05-29 17:00:09                       <NA> <NA>
## 5 2021-05-29 17:01:09     http://www.bbc.co.uk/     
## 6 2021-05-29 17:02:09                       <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: As illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937102/how-to-split-a-url), the `httr` package will do the heavy lfting for you.  No point in reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First capture group `^([^//]*//[^/]*/{1})` captures everything from start till two // and then // and everything till / and then / just one
- second capture group captures everything remaining till end

```
df %>% extract(url, c("Domain", "Path"), "^([^//]*//[^/]*/{1})(.*$)")

             datetime                     Domain                                                                         Path
1 2021-05-29 16:57:09 https://stackoverflow.com/ questions/67755241/how-do-i-put-row-data-from-a-database-into-a-php-variable
2 2021-05-29 16:58:09 https://stackoverflow.com/                                                                             
3 2021-05-29 16:59:09 https://stackoverflow.com/                                                                       hacker
4 2021-05-29 17:00:09 https://stackoverflow.com/                               jobs?so_medium=StackOverflow&so_source=SiteNav
5 2021-05-29 17:01:09      http://www.bbc.co.uk/                                                                             
6 2021-05-29 17:02:09        http://www.bbc.com/                                                        weather/2643743?day=3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex -

```
tidyr::extract(df, url, c('Domain', 'path'), '(https?://.*?/)(.*)')

#             datetime                     Domain
#1 2021-05-29 16:57:09 https://stackoverflow.com/
#2 2021-05-29 16:58:09 https://stackoverflow.com/
#3 2021-05-29 16:59:09 https://stackoverflow.com/
#4 2021-05-29 17:00:09 https://stackoverflow.com/
#5 2021-05-29 17:01:09      http://www.bbc.co.uk/
#6 2021-05-29 17:02:09        http://www.bbc.com/
                                                                          path
#1 questions/67755241/how-do-i-put-row-data-from-a-database-into-a-php-variable
#2                                                                             
#3                                                                       hacker
#4                               jobs?so_medium=StackOverflow&so_source=SiteNav
#5                                                                             
#6                                                        weather/2643743?day=3
```

Same regex can be used in base R `strcapture` -

```
strcapture('(https?://.*?/)(.*)', df$url, 
           proto = list(Domain = character(), path = character()))
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! What if a site uses http:// instead of https:// ? Can it be modified to use both http:// and https:// ?